# Type 'ServerTrustPolicy' has no member 'certificatesInBundle'

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I want to pin certificate that is in the project bundle.

```
.pinCertificates(
        certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle,
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true
      )
```

This works in Swift 2 but when I update to Swift 3 I got this error:

```
Type 'ServerTrustPolicy' has no member 'certificatesInBundle'
```

Anyone who encountered the same issue? May I know what have you replaced with 'certificatesInBundle'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function was renamed. Check this:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift#L122